# HTML file not loading for CartoDB.js using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, carto, web-mapping, html

I am trying to create a web map that uses a layer hosted on CartoDB and a basemap created in Mapbox studio. Never mind adding the basemap to the L.map, I cannot get the cartoDB layer to draw at all. My code is below (without the Mapbox portion):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>RCC Global Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        function main() {
            map = new L.map("map", {
                center: [0,0]
                zoom: 2
            });

            cartodb.createLayer("map", 'https://mccook3.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/3136e62c-98bf-11e5-8d04-0ef24382571b/viz.json')
            .addTo(map)
            .done(function(layers) {
                var sublayer = layers.getSubLayer(0);
                subLayer.setInteraction(true);
            });
        }
        window.onload = main;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createLayer` function accepts a `map` object, not the id of the div element.

Comment: You are correct. Simple mistake on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `cartodb.createLayer()` when you really want to use `cartodb.createViz()`. Double check [the documentation](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/getting-started/#creating-a-visualization-from-scratch).

Comment: He wants to use the `createLayer` to be able to create first a map by hand and add the mapbox layer before the CartoDB one. Docs [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/api-methods/#cartodbcreatelayermap-layersource--options--callback)